# Regex scala: Format matching and padding

Tags: regex, scala

Correct input format: xxxx/yyyy/zzzz i.e. 4 chars for each part. **Total length of the string (not counting "/") should always be 12.**

Input can be: xxx/yyy/zzz then it should be padded to come out as 0xxx/0yyy/0zzz

At this stage at least one "/" will be there. If there are 2 parts then we need 6 chars for both.

Looking for a regex with padding logic in Scala.

```
// line to tune: 
val matchThis = raw"(\d{4})/(\d{4})/(\d{4})".r

val valids = List ("1/6", "123456/1", "1/123456", "123456/123456", "1/2/3", "1234/1234/1234", "012/12/3", "1/01/012")
val invalids = List ("/6", "1234567/1", "1/1234567", "1234567/1234567", "/2/3", "1/2/", "12345/1234/1234", "012/12345/3", "1/01/012345")

def tester (input: String) = {
  input match {
      case matchThis(_*) => "It's valid!"
      case _ => "Need some work" /*???*/
  }
}

valids.map (s => tester(s))
invalids.map (s => tester(s))
```

Comment: And if it contains leading zeros already? How about "0001/0100/0123/"? But "01/100/123" is invalid? How many leading zeros should be added, if we have 2 substrings?

Comment: "0001/0100/0123/" is good, we don't have to do anything else. While for "01/100/123", it'd need to be padded to "0001/0100/0123/". Final count should be 12 when parts are added. At least there will be 2 parts, ideally 3, and no more.

Comment: But "//" cant be filled to "0000/0000/0000" or "/" to "000000/000000"?

Comment: We'd ignore such cases, they don't provide any value to downstream.

Comment: could you update your question with bounds tests? this might help yourself also.

Comment: You should provide two lists, one with all matching, one with all failing expressions and a method, to map over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't bulletproof but I think it covers most of what you've described.

```
val valid = raw"(\d{1,6})/(\d{1,6})(?:/(\d{1,4}))?".r
val output = input match {
  case valid(a,b,null) => f"$a%6s/$b%6s"       replaceAll(" ","0")
  case valid(a,b,c)    => f"$a%4s/$b%4s/$c%4s" replaceAll(" ","0")
  case _ => "invalid"
}
```

---

A little more complete.

```
val valid = raw"(\d{1,4})/(\d{1,4})/(\d{1,4})|(\d{1,6})/(\d{1,6})".r
val output = input match {
  case valid(null,null,null,a,b) => f"$a%6s/$b%6s"       replaceAll(" ","0")
  case valid(a,b,c,null,null)    => f"$a%4s/$b%4s/$c%4s" replaceAll(" ","0")
  case _ => "invalid"
}
```

Comment: returns `2345/1234/1234, 0012/2345/0003` for input `12345/1234/1234, 012/12345/3` but should return invalid, invalid.